# Android Application в модуле

Tags: android

Подключил к проекту другой проект в виде модуля.File->Project Structure->dependencies->add module dependency.  В файле build.gradle поменял application на library в apply plugin. При сборки gradle выдал ошибку, мол неможет замержить AndroidManifest причина android:name= в  конфликтует(у меня 2 application, один в основном модуле, другой в подключенном). Удалил тег android:name= в  (в подключаемом модуле) все собралось отлично, но теперь возник вопрос как  подключить свой класс унаследованный от Application в подключенном модуле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application должен быть только в приложении, а библиотека может тебе предоставить какой-то базовый Application.

Ты можешь в своей библиотеке создать абстрактный класс Application, в нем будет нужная тебе реализация. Соответственно в манифесте библиотеки ничего не указываешь.

Затем, в приложении ты наследуешься от своего абстрактного Application из библиотеки и прописываешь Application в манифесте приложения.

Comment: А если у меня будет больше чем одна библиотека, то что делать? я же не могу унаследоваться от всех классов Application(во всех библиотеках)

Comment: Тогда используй композицию и вообще не юзай абстрактный Application

Comment: Поясните пожалуста как я должен использовать композицию чтобы решить эту проблему?

Comment: Какая задача стоит? Зачем вам вообще Application в библиотеке? Библиотека - не приложение. Может вам можно создать отдельные сервисные классы и их заюзать в основном Application, вот и все. Просто если у вас появляются озвученные проблемы, значит у вас что-то не в порядке с архитектурой, ели ее можно таковой назвать.

Comment: Согласен с @Алексей. Вмешательство в класс Application из вне модуля приложения это крайне специфический случай и скорее всего автор может решить свою проблему не прибегая к этому.